# Bootstrap: Center Label and Input in form

Tags: html, css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an problem that i have not been able to finde any answer. I have section of the view: [image] 
If the label on the right is to long for the view, it will of course break, but the input does not follow down to be centered with the label. Are there any way to do that. So it looks something like this instead:
[image]
Here is the code

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 noPadding">
            <label class="checkboxlabel control-label col-xs-4 col-md-2" for="EmEquipDescEnglish">
                @Html.Action("GetLabel", "Translatable", new { key = "MMS_EquipmentManagement2" })
            </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control requiredField validateField translateString imgtooltip" data-isvalid="false" id="EmEquipDescEnglish" @Html.Action("GetString", "Translatable", new { key = "MMS_EquipmentManagement19" }) data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please share your code or fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I've made you a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3fx4cchs/
It's made with position absolute, there is also a version where you could use `display:table;` but i chose this one.

Comment: You need to include the code from your fiddle in your answer.